# How to manipulate two arrays using void function

Tags: c

This code is asking the user to fill out to matrix and then it calls a void function to add them together. I have a [www.ideone.com](http://ideone.com/9Ulbo)
I cannot change much of the code also. It is requeired to have all those define statements and a void function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NCOL1 2
#define NCOL2 2
#define NROW1 2
#define NROW2 2
#define NCOL3 2
#define NROW3 2

int main (void)
{
    //Initiate variables
    double a, b;
    int    i, j;
    void   addarray(double a, double b);
    double ans;
    double arr1[NCOL1][NROW1], arr2[NCOL2][NROW1];

    //Ask user to enter numbers for the first matrix
    printf("Please enter numbers for Matrix 1 :\n ");
    for (i = 0; i < NCOL1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NROW1; j++) {
            scanf("%lf", &arr1[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //Ask user to enter numbers for the second matrix
    printf("Please enter numbers for Matrix 2 :\n ");
    for (i = 0; i < NCOL2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NROW2; j++) {
            scanf("%lf", &arr2[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //Iterate through void function and print out result
    for (i = 0; i < NCOL3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NROW3; j++) {
            addarray(arr1[i][j], arr2[i][j]);
            printf("%lf", ans);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void addarray (double a, double b)
{
    int i,j;
    double arrsum[NCOL3][NROW3];
    for (i = 0; i < NCOL3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NROW3; j++) {
            arrsum[i][j] = a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what your question is.  Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: Consider passing the arrays to be added by reference for the void function. Have a third reference for output array.

Comment: If the function must be `void`, you either have to pass another parameter in or add the first to the second in-place. Also your functions should probably be taking arrays, not scalar values.

Comment: And now what? It should buy you a beer or what's the problem...

Comment: You can't define functions inside other functions in C.

Comment: @mert the question is tagged as C, which does not have references (although it does have pointers).

Comment: @H2CO3: If he doesn't have a problem, then he should buy us beers... then none of us will care if he doesn't have a problem.

Comment: @user1082764: Are you going to acknowledge any of the help people have provided to you here? I personally spent a bit of time trying to understand your question and even provided lots of code and suggestions to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: A better solution to the problem is:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define NCOL1 2
#define NCOL2 2
#define NROW1 2
#define NROW2 2
#define NCOL3 2
#define NROW3 2


void addarray(double a[NROW1][NCOL1], double b[NROW1][NCOL1], double (*c)[NCOL1]);


int main(void)
        {
  //Initiate variables
  double a,b;
  int i,j;
  double ans;
  double arr1[NCOL1][NROW1], arr2[NCOL2][NROW1];
  double arrsum[NCOL1][NROW1];

  //Ask user to enter numbers for the first matrix
  printf("Please enter numbers for Matrix 1 :\n ");
    for(i=0;i<NCOL1;i++){
       for(j=0;j<NROW1;j++){
         scanf("%lf",&arr1[i][j]);
       }
    }
  //Ask user to enter numbers for the second matrix
    printf("Please enter numbers for Matrix 2 :\n ");
    for(i=0;i<NCOL2;i++){
      for(j=0;j<NROW2;j++){
        scanf("%lf",&arr2[i][j]);
      }
    }


    addarray( arr1, arr2, &arrsum[0] );

    printf("Output of added arrays\n");
    for(i=0;i<NCOL3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<NROW3;j++){
                    printf("%lf ", arrsum[i][j]);
            }
        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;
}

void addarray(double a[NROW1][NCOL1], double b[NROW1][NCOL1], double (*c)[NCOL1])
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<NCOL3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<NROW3;j++)
        {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

**But, with minimal changes the following will also work.**

It looks like addarray() is putting it's results into a local matrix called arrsum[][]. For this program to work you will most likely want to make arrsum[][] available to the rest of the program ( although a global array is not a great idea ).

Without testing or compiling the code you should make these changes at a minimum:

1- Remove `double arrsum[NCOL3][NROW3];` from `addarray()`

```
void addarray(double a,double b)
{
        int i,j;

        for(i=0;i<NCOL3;i++){
                for(j=0;j<NROW3;j++){
                        arrsum[i][j]=a+b;
                }
}
```

2- Make `arrsum[][]` global

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define NCOL1 2
#define NCOL2 2
#define NROW1 2
#define NROW2 2
#define NCOL3 2
#define NROW3 2

/****  add declaration of arrsum[][] here ****/
double arrsum[NCOL3][NROW3];
```

I've gone and rewritten parts of the program, compiled and tested it. The new code is below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define NCOL1 2
#define NCOL2 2
#define NROW1 2
#define NROW2 2
#define NCOL3 2
#define NROW3 2


void addarray(double a,double b);


double arrsum[NCOL3][NROW3];

int main(void)
        {
  //Initiate variables
  double a,b;
  int i,j;
  double ans;
  double arr1[NCOL1][NROW1], arr2[NCOL2][NROW1];
  //Ask user to enter numbers for the first matrix
  printf("Please enter numbers for Matrix 1 :\n ");
    for(i=0;i<NCOL1;i++){
       for(j=0;j<NROW1;j++){
         scanf("%lf",&arr1[i][j]);
       }
    }
  //Ask user to enter numbers for the second matrix
    printf("Please enter numbers for Matrix 2 :\n ");
    for(i=0;i<NCOL2;i++){
      for(j=0;j<NROW2;j++){
        scanf("%lf",&arr2[i][j]);
      }
    }
    //Iterate through void function and print out result
    for(i=0;i<NCOL3;i++){
      for(j=0;j<NROW3;j++){
        addarray(arr1[i][j],arr2[i][j]);
//        printf("%lf",ans);
      }
    }

    printf("Output of added arrays\n");
    for(i=0;i<NCOL3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<NROW3;j++){
                    printf("%lf ", arrsum[i][j]);
            }
        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;
}

void addarray(double a,double b)
{
        int i,j;

        for(i=0;i<NCOL3;i++){
                for(j=0;j<NROW3;j++){
                        arrsum[i][j]=a+b;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: You can't pass an array to a function using an argument type like `double a1[][]`.  You can only omit the dimension of the first (left-most) level of the array.  Otherwise, the compiler won't know how to do the array arithmetic.  Similarly, a third parameter of type `double**` is not the same thing as a two-dimensional array (a pointer to an array of pointers, perhaps, but not a 2D array).

Comment: Yes, I figured that out and deleted that portion of my response. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What is your question?  Thank you for providing code, but it's not clear what exactly you are trying to do or what the code is currently doing incorrectly.  Please update your question with more details about what you are trying to accomplish and what specifically you need help with.

General Advice:  If you want to manipulate arrays using a function, then the function needs to take a pointer to the array as a parameter.

Also, your `addarray()` function is only modifying the array `arrsum`, which lives within the scope of that function.  Since that function never does anything with `arrsum` after initializing its elements, that entire function is essentially a no-op.